Clock time stuck from last night
I have noticed that there can be a few seconds after reopening the lid of my Macbook that the time just started again from the moment that the laptop was put to sleep - e.g. 1:30AM. It is not stuck : the seconds do start to increment.  But then within a few seconds the time does get updated.
Well except for this time. The time according to my laptop is still in the 1:30AM (plus about ten minutes) timeframe.
Note that the Date and Time option to "Set time and date automatically" is set:

Yes it would be possible to use date to update the clock, but why is this happening and is there a fix?
Update The date / time did finally change now, it took about twenty minutes.

I would not be surprised if the cause was your Mac not being able to reach its NTP source (time server) EG network issues in general or just with that particular subsystem. If it is not too inconvenient, I would try the 'universal' first troubleshooting step (reboot) as this would "reset" the macOS subsystems and possibly clear that error.

I posted this problem while the time was off by multiple hours: it's unique to the time server. btw this happened again today - this time maybe five minutes of "hey it's still midnight-ish".  I found a potential fix: to kill timed : it will restart automatically and [maybe?] find the actual correct time.
